# Getting wrong volumes with yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, finance, yahoo-finance, trading

I am trying to come up with different strategies for my own protfolio by using yfinance and tulipy as my main ingredients but I'm having issues with the volumes that i get from yfinance. Keep in mind that i am working with daily minute data here.

This is just a random example but if you look at the screenshot you will see that at 11:16 a.m. the volume is 136981
[image: AAPL volume]

but if i go and check on Trading View the volume is always different
[image: trading view data]

as you can see on the left the volume is 3.047K

Everything else seems to be right and I'm having no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other yfinance users have reported inconsistent results - https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/626

Maybe you need to find another source for market data?